# Call to a member function getInternalRequest() on null when using ResponseCode

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, codeception

So im having this Problem and i can't find any solutions, anywhere.

I am trying to check: after the a URL redirect the ResponseCode is 200...which i is because i can see it in the Console.

How every when running this code

```
public function responseCodeWifi(\AcceptanceTester $I, REST $rest)
{

    $I->wantTo('Check redirect for de/wifi-welcome');

    $I->amOnPage('/de/wifi-welcome');
    $I->seeInCurrentUrl('/wifi-welcome');

    $rest->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
}
```

i get the following error in my Shell

> [Error] Call to a member function getInternalRequest() on null

Im using chrome and selenium.

EDIT:
using

```
use AcceptanceTester;
use Codeception\Util\HttpCode;
use Codeception\Module\REST;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST module can't inspect responses of WebDriver module.

If your Acceptance suite used PhpBrowser module, you could use REST module to inspect responses by making it dependent on PhpBrowser:

```
modules:
   enabled:
       - PhpBrowser
       - REST:
           depends: PhpBrowser
```

And call seeResponseCodeIs in you test code as

```
$I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
```